# How to design a simple monitoring library in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, software-design

Suppose, I am developing an application, which consists of a few components. Now I would like to write a function to return the application status

```
case class Status(...)
def status[A](a:A):Status = {...} // A - data used to calculate the status
```

This function probably should call other functions, which returns statuses of the components, and each of those component functions calls other functions, that return statuses of the subcomponents and so on, and so on

How would you design a library of such functions in Scala? Do these functions look like a `monad` ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two obvious approaches here. The first uses pattern matching to decompose the data structure:

```
// Just use Boolean for status
type Status = Boolean

trait Statusable
class class A(isOk : Boolean) extends Statusable
class class B(a : A) extends Statusable
class class C(first : B, second : B) extends Statusable

def status(a : Statusable) : Status = a match {
  case a : A => a.isOk
  case B(a) => status(b.a)
  case C(first, second) => status(first) && status(second)
}

status(C(B(A(true)), B(A(false))))
// returns false

status(C(B(A(true)), B(A(true))))
// returns true
```

Now, you might be thinking that that trait 'Stat' looks a little horrible, and you might not want to enforce that your data classes derive from a common base. In this case, type classes come to the rescue:

```
trait HasStatus[A] { def getStatus(a : A) : Status }
object HasStatus {

  def status[A : HasStatus](a : A) = implicitly[HasStatus[A]].getStatus(a)

  implicit object AHasStatus extends HasStatus[A] {
    def getStatus(a : A) = a.isOk
  }
  implicit object BHasStatus extends HasStatus[B] {
    def getStatus(b : B) = status(b.a)
  }
  implicit object CHasStatus extends HasStatus[C] {
    def getStatus(c : C) = status(c.first) && status(c.second)
  }
}
import HasStatus._
status(C(B(A(true)), B(A(false))))
//returns false
```